# Magento not showing error messages on login page after redirect from cart

Tags: php, magento

I added a redirect to checkout/onepage.phtml to redirect customers to the login/register page before proceeding to checkout from the cart. I did not modify Accountcontroller.php or login.phtml.

The redirect works fine, but the error messages on the login page get lost (e.g. wrong password, unknown email address are not showing up). The messages on the other pages work fine, and the messages on the login page only start to work again after deleting the cookies.

The code I use for the redirect at the beginning of onepage.html:

```
      if (!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
             header("Location: /customer/account/login/");
             exit();
      }
```

In login.phtml `<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>` is called correctly.

I also tried extending the redirect code with

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("Error message");
session_write_close();
```

which displays the message directly after the redirect and not when a wrong password/email is entered. Is there a way to make the messages work without creating a custom controller/module?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use PHP's `header` function, use Magento's inbuilt redirect method.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Error to display here.');
$this->_redirect('customer/account/login');
```

Comment: You are right about the redirect but unfortunately this does not solve my problem. Using ->addError will display the error instantly like "Product has been added to cart" but I need the error to show only after form submit when the user entered a wrong email/password

Comment: Using PHP's `header()` seems to be necessary if you are trying to redirect during an AJAX request, unless I am mistaken.